# Build Failed on Continuous integration with SQL Server Data Tools and Team Foundation Server

Tags: database, tfs, msbuild, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I am trying to implement this idea https://www.sqlshack.com/continuous-integration-sql-server-data-tools-team-foundation-server/ and I am getting this error:

> Error Deploy72002: Unable to connect to master or target server 'DatabseTest'. You must have a user with the same password in master or target server 'DatabaseTest'.

I did the idea in a very simple way I created a database for the test in a Development server (just one table with an ID and Name columns), I created a database project on the visual studio, I create a script to insert a few rows in the only table in the database. Then I create a publish profile, I added the connection to the 'DatabaseTest' in the 'DEV' server, the user I am using for the access to the database is a user with admin permissions, the script associated with the publish profile is the only script in the solution the one for insert the rows. I made the check in and I created a build definition. I am trying to make the project build successfully, so I just add a Build Solution Task, in the MSBuild Arguments this is what I am passing:

```
 /t:build /t:publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath=Database_Testing_Profile.publish.xml
```

And I am getting the error from the beginning of the question.

Can someone please give an idea, about what is the problem??

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us what you `Database_Testing_Profile.publish.xml` looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

First, The password won’t be stored in publish profile file after saving it, you need to add it manually (User Name=XXX;Password=XXX)

Secondly, sure the Target Platform is correct (Right click the project=>Properties=>Project Settings)

On the other hand, there is an article that may benefit you: [Using MSBuild to publish a VS 2012 SSDT .sqlproj database project the same way as a VS 2010 .dbproj database project (using command line arguments to specify the database to publish to)](http://blog.danskingdom.com/using-msbuild-to-publish-a-vs-2012-ssdt-sqlproj-database-project-the-same-way-as-a-vs-2010-dbproj-database-project/)